# Scheme: list counter

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I want to implement a function that counts the number of occurrences of elements in a list.

The function call would be like this:

```
(count '(a a x a 11 11 a 11 a))
```

The function output should be (list of pairs):

```
( (a . 5) (x . 1) (11 . 3) )
```

Thank you for advice how implement count procedure best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" depends on your needs and constraints; here's an example implementation using Racket's build-in procedures that is short but probably slow for large lists:

```
(define (mycount lst)
  (map
   (lambda (e) (cons e (count (curry eqv? e) lst)))
   (remove-duplicates lst)))
```

then

```
> (mycount '(a a x a 11 11 a 11 a))
'((a . 5) (x . 1) (11 . 3))
```

If you can be more specific about your constraints then we can probably help you better.